# Null Pointer exception while Fetching the file path from jfilechooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

[image: File chooser UI implemented using jfilechooser in JAVA SWING]

On clicking the open button, I am trying to fetch the path of the file, including the file name I opened.

Code:

```
private void jFileChooser1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
    JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
    String path=chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();//error
    System.out.println(path);
}
```

But I am getting a null pointer exception in the commented (`//errror`) line.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Before the chooser is displayed to the user, it won't ***have*** a selected file (unless set by the programmer)!

Comment: read the javadocs `int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
            chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    }`

Comment: Instead of creating a new `JFileChooser` instance, you need to get the selected file from the event.

Comment: @AndrewThompson so what is the order of doing this? Kindly suggest me on this, I am jsut migrating from python to JAVA

Comment: Can't speak for Python, but for Java there's this marvellous resource that can be found with a search string of 'hot to X' where in this case X is 'jfilechooser'. Top hit is [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). Book mark the tutorial.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you.

Comment: BTW - that should have been '**how** to X'.. :P  But I'm hoping you figured that out. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open it at first!

Use this sample code:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: thanks it is working. But how do I restrict this action only to "open" button in the file chooser.

Comment: @vikky2405 : this is already done by the `if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)` condition .